# Error when deploying application: Nested exception Resolution

Tags: oracle, exception, jdeveloper

I created an application in Jdeveloper 10g. I have created a war for my app. Then I attempted to deploy my app to an application server (Oracle Enterprises manager). When I deploy, it is throwing an error which is given below:

```
Failed to deploy web application "test". Failed to deploy web application "test". . Nested exception

Resolution:

Base Exception:

com.evermind.server.rmi.OrionRemoteException
Class not found:
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException;
nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException.
Class not found:
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException;
nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException
```

So please help me out with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a library file (presumably the spring framework). You can either add it to your server in in the library folder for the app server, or you can include it in you war file in the WEB-INF/libs/ folder.